# How to find the address of a table-type element without using XPath

Tags: java, selenium

Is there a way to iterate through a table without using XPath?
At the moment, I am iterating with a for loop like this:

```
String a = "//*[@id='mainData']/table/tbody/tr[";
String b = "]/td[2]";
int[] comparison = new int[101];
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    String c = a + Integer.toString(i) + b;
    WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(c)));
        correct[i] = element.getText();
```

But I would like to use dynamic XPathing (like .//*[@class='x']). But then how can I find the column address, and how do I iterate through the column?

Comment: Are you asking how to avoid XPaths entirely or are you looking for a way to get all the rows in one go and then iterate through the data without resorting to XPaths again?
Also it is unclear whether you want to iterate row by row or column by column given the way your question is formulated.

Comment: I want to use dynamic xPathing instead of xpaths generated by Firebug for example. And then i have to copy all elements from the column inside an array. So i need to iterate through the column and get results from each line in an array.

Comment: I'll be back to answer this with an optimised solution in a few hours, the one provided by @metar is terribly inefficient and is no better than what you've already done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate your table the like:

```
// count number of rows
int sizeRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='mainData']/table/tbody/tr")).size();

// iterate rows
for(int tableRow = 1; tableRow <= sizeRows; tableRow++) {
   String rowLocator = String.format("//*[@id='mainData']/table/tbody/tr[%d]", tableRow);

   String column1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(rowLocator+"/td[1]")).getText().trim();
   String column2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(rowLocator+"/td[2]")).getText().trim();
 ..
 }
```